# Simple date format parses 2k11 like values which should throw an exception

Tags: java, validation, simpledateformat

I am trying to validate dates using simple data format and it parses strange dates.

```
 val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM, yyyy")
      dateFormat.setLenient(false)
      dateFormat.parse("01 Jan, 2k11")
```

Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2

fast time : -62104253400000

cDate : C.E. 2-01-01T00:00:00.000+0530

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Also they won’t show the bad behaviour you’ve observed with `SimpleDateFormat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started digging through the source code for [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/cff1616/luni/src/main/java/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.java), and read enough to glean what appears to be happening here.  What is happening is that your year component `2k11` is being interpreted as a two digit year (actually one digit, `2`), and everything that follows is being ignored as not being part of the date pattern.  Consider the following code which produces the same result:

```
  DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM, yyyy");
  dateFormat.setLenient(false);
  Date blah = dateFormat.parse("01 Jan, 2 Jon Skeet");
  System.out.println(blah);
```

This prints:

```
Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 CET 2
```

As you can see, the intepreted year is 2, and the `Jon Skeet` blurb was ignored.  To understand exactly *why* `SimpleDateFormat` is doing this, read the source code.

Comment: Rather than the source code I recommend [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-). `parse` is declared in the superclass, `DateFormat`, and it “Parses text from the beginning of the given string to produce a date. The method may not use the entire text of the given string.”

Comment: @OleV.V. That helps too :-) ... I figured this was a quirk which the Javadoc conveniently would not mention.

Comment: I agree that the `SimpleDateFormat` documentation is not always complete, so I understand your *a priori* suspicion.